# How to mix grid and flex and grow one of the flex elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My home dashboard is made up of independent components. The components themselves, inside, are of different nature: some are managed by a CSS Grid, some by a CSS Flexbox, some are default blocks.

I would like to force the arrangements of these components so that they are stacked, and that one of them takes all available space.

## The design so far

Up to now I had a `justify-content: space-around;` on the most exterior element (the general application container) and my components were aligned as expected:

```css
.border {
  margin: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.boxofelements {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
}

.bigbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox border">
  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Changes I wanted to make

I then wanted to change the stack and have the middle box take all available space below itself. Something along the lines of

[image]

To do so I removed the `justify-content: space-around;` element and tried to forcefully `grow` the middle element:

```css
.border {
  margin: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.boxofelements {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
}

.bigbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  /* no more space around
    justify-content: space-around;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox border">
  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border" style="grow: 1">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, well, nothing happened.

**What is the correct incantation to say "make it so that element takes all available space in the axis, "behind" its border"?** (which in my case means "below" and would mean "on the right" if the axis was on the row)

Comment: there is no property called `grow`. It's `flex-grow` (voting to close this as simply typo issueà

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe `flex-grow` is what you are looking for.

```css
.border {
  margin: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.boxofelements {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
}

.bigbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  /* no more space around
    justify-content: space-around;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox border">
  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border" style="flex-grow: 1;">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxofelements border">
    <div class="element border">one</div>
    <div class="element border">two</div>
    <div class="element border">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```